# My question is about how this happening over and over again when I use EOLINKER to manage my APIs, I can' t use automated testing funciton

Tags: php, automated-tests

When I use EOLINKER's automated testing function. I tried to set up a demo API to test whether it can fulfill my requirement but it shows:

> 1:After-response Script execution error: SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode. at Object.evalAfterScript (chrome-extension://mdbgchaihbacjfjeikflfbelidihhmfn/js/bundle/test.min.js:2599:18) at Object. (chrome-extension://mdbgchaihbacjfjeikflfbelidihhmfn/js/bundle/test.min.js:7142:107) at i (chrome-extension://mdbgchaihbacjfjeikflfbelidihhmfn/js/libs/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2:28017) at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (chrome-extension://mdbgchaihbacjfjeikflfbelidihhmfn/js/libs/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2:28783) at A (chrome-extension://mdbgchaihbacjfjeikflfbelidihhmfn/js/libs/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4:14035) at XMLHttpRequest. (chrome-extension://mdbgchaihbacjfjeikflfbelidihhmfn/js/libs/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4:16323)

1. I have tried to change the json check type.
2. I have also tried to delete parameters I don't really need but also the same.

Response check for my API

```
response={"code":000000,"msg":"SUCCESS","data":{"uuid":"fjsnby350fr14fiw"},array:[{a:1},{a:'2'},{a:3}]};
```

I expect the output to be the same as user login API.
It could generate a token that will be used at reset password API  and I use a browser extension to enhance my test efficiency.

```
{"status":"000000","userInfo":{"loginTime":"2018-1-1 00:00:00","token":"m928j3x2oyr198ny37ex"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"code":000000` is probably your problem. It needs to either be just plain `0` or the string `"000000"`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_octal

Comment: Your website is helpful and thank you, have you ever meet this kind of problem?